# Removing app name from url in proxypassreverse setup

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I have been able to map my application to the domain in a manner I found after doing some research (copy-paste) on internet.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ProxyPass        /MyApp http://localhost:8080/MyApp
   ProxyPassReverse /MyApp http://localhost:8080/MyApp
   ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost example.com
   ProxyPreserveHost On


 RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com/MyApp
</VirtualHost>
```

The rewrite works fine and whenever I open example.com it redirects to example.com/MyApp . My query is, how can I make it not redirect and deliver the MyApp at example.com/ without any redirect. Just plain simple mapping of the MyApp to the root of the domain. The rewrite works fine, but certainly don't want app name in url.

Comment: Using the proxy flag (`[P]`) of [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) should do it: `RewriteRule ^/$ http://example.com/MyApp [P]`

Comment: If you have control of docroot, it might also work to set it to `/MyApp`

Comment: I am in control of my server. can you please post your answer related to docroot, so that I can give it a try. And I tried [p] flag but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your war file to ROOT.war to make it the root webapp in Tomcat. Then adjust the paths accordingly in the Apache config:

```
ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: Yes, that would basically proxy all requests to Tomcat. Of course you can only have one root webapp, but you can have ohter webapps with context names.